# BST: unbound identifier in module in: BST Error

Tags: scheme, racket

The code is an implementation of a Binary Search Tree

Calling the function (searchBST BST 5) yields in the following error:

BST: unbound identifier in module in: BST

The problem lies with the BST parameter. The call to search takes two inputs and i provide both inputs, but if it crashes on call then the code is wrong?

Any clues what the caused this error? Thank you.

```
(define (searchBST BST key)

(cond
     [
      (null? BST)
      (list key)
      ]
     [
      (equal? key (currentKey BST))

        (list key (currentValue BST))
        ]

       [(< key (currentKey BST) )

        (searchBST (leftChild BST) key)
         ]

       [(> key (currentKey BST) )

         (searchBST (rightChild BST) key)

        ]
        )
     )


(searchBST BST 5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `BST` is the name of a *parameter*, that is expected by most of the defined procedures. You have to pass an actual *value* for it, presumably by building a binary search tree and optionally binding it to a variable. For example, to build a simple tree and bind it to a variable named `BST`:

```
(define BST (build 5 'ok '() '()))
(searchBST BST 5)
```